# ERROR: Failure processing PNG image android

Tags: android, xml, image, widget

Hello I build a widget and it contains an imageview for title and content divider
well just like always I imported my image to the drawable folder

i declared the image on my widget xml layout like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_widget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/divider"/>
```

it's divider.9.png at my drawable folder
so, when i start to compile this it turns out error
not at the xml file but at the image itself

and when i looked at the console it says:

```
ERROR: Failure processing PNG image /home/drikvi/workspace/AnimList/res/drawable-hdpi/divider.9.png
[2011-06-23 15:18:59 - AnimList] W/ResourceType( 2305): Bad XML block: header size 2433    or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2011-06-23 15:18:59 - AnimList] W/ResourceType( 2305): Bad XML block: header size 2433   or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
```

i really have no idea with this?

any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your image is not a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and it should be if it has the `.9.png` extension. Try renaming it to `divider.png` and see if that works.

Comment: well i've patched it before... i'll try it :)

Comment: Well, try my suggestion. If it works there's a problem with your 9-patch format. If it still fails, there's a problem with your png format.

Comment: well, it works! but i still need 9 patch image... hmmmm..., ok i will repatch it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below solution ..

Initially remove src attribute from ImageView ... save xml layout and then build the project. after that try to user divider.png instead of divder.9.png in 3 dpi folder in resources dir. Then again replace the code you commented out in xml layout .. Build again.. now there's should not be any problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
<ImageView    
        android:id="@+id/img_widget"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"    
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:src="@drawable/divider.9"/>
```

Check Image name divider.9

Comment: You don't need to include a .9 extension to the drawable name if you're using 9-patch images.

Comment: You cant't use .9 in image name

Comment: Yes you can, provided it is in 9-patch format. But then you do not need to include the .9 in the drawable reference name. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch if you don't believe me.